# How can I examine the JVM bytecode for a clojure function?

Tags: clojure, jvm

In trying to optimize C and LISP, looking at the assembler code output by the compiler can be a great help.

Clojure presumably compiles to a JVM bytecode that would be equally helpful.

How do I see it?

Comment: Please be aware that optimizing the bytecode might not actually produce any positive results. See [this interview](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/goetz_qa.html#CodePerformsWell). It talks about writing Java, but it basically applies to all languages that produce bytecode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clojure dynamically compiles all the Clojure code to bytecode at the runtime. I am not sure how you can see this dynamically compiled bytecode. However, you can do *Ahead Of Time* (AOT) compilation of your Clojure code yourself and that will generate .class files. Then you can use `javap` to see the bytecode.

Use the `compile` function in Clojure/core to compile your namespace:

> compile
>   function
>
> Usage: (compile lib)
>
> Compiles the namespace named by the symbol lib into a set of
>   classfiles. The source for the lib must be in a proper
>   classpath-relative directory. The output files will go into the
>   directory specified by *compile-path*, and that directory too must
>   be in the classpath.

Then use `javap`:

```
javap -l -c -s -private MyClass
```

Comment: Note that you have to leave off the .class extension. Confused me for a minute or so.

Answer (score 7):

I made a small library and lein-plugin for this, check it out:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/_BBXpt_GPIw/WWq2VbWkEKEJ

https://github.com/gtrak/no.disassemble

It has the added advantage of not requiring AOT.

Answer (score 4):

Some hand-made solutions:

- [Java Bytecode Editor](http://www.cs.ioc.ee/~ando/jbe/)
- the JDK's [Java Class File Disassembler (javap)](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GPCK_enGB367GB368&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javap)
- if using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), you can use the [Bytecode Outline plug-in](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/bytecode/index.html) or [Bytecode Visualizer](http://www.drgarbage.com/bytecode-visualizer.html).
- [Google for more](https://encrypted.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+view+class+bytecode) :)

Comment: May I ask why the down-vote? As far as I know, these are valid answers on how to examine the bytecode of compiled class files, so they are relevant to Clojure. Maybe there's a more Clojure-y way, but it still works just as well. If something I'm saying is wrong, please tell me what and why.

Comment: I suspect you were down-voted because you said "Google it". It's general knowledge on SO that any well-asked and serious question that hasn't been asked on SO before is an okay question to ask. The idea is for SO to be a part of the google results.

Comment: Ah. That sounds fair enough, though I didn't mean it as a putting down the OP and implying lazyness on his/her part, just that it provides timeless answers with good results considering it's a fairly common question for JVM languages. My bad, I'll do better next time.

Comment: I was the OP, and I thought yours was a great answer and upvoted it. Thanks. I accepted the other one because it told me exactly what to type!